# у меня вылазиет ошибка я не понимаю что не так

Tags: python, tkinter

я сделал программу которая вычисляет пароль от вай фай по BSSID и когда писал для неё интерфейс вылезла куча ошибок https://disk.yandex.ru/i/ua-VAIdOhYOw9w
**вот мой код**:

````
        
from tkinter import *
from math import floor
root=Tk()
root.title("brute")

x = root.winfo_screenwidth()
y = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(int(x*1), int(y*1)))


My_label=Label(root,text="possible passwords",font=("Arial",50,"bold"))
My_label.pack()

name=StringVar()

BSSID = Entry(width=20,bd=5)
BSSID.place(x=x/2.3,y=y/3)

bssd1=BSSID.get().replace(":","",1)

def play():
  MAC = bssd1
  один = b = (int(MAC,16) & 0xFFFFFF) % 10000000
  a = 0
  while b:
    a += 3 * (b % 10)
    b = floor(b / 10)
    a += b % 10
    b = floor(b / 10)
  d = (один * 10) + ((10 - (a % 10)) % 10)
  c = str(int(d))
  result = c.zfill(8)

my_botton = Button(text="начать",width=112, height=5,bg="yellow",fg="gold",command = play)
my_botton.place(x=400,y=400)





root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Тест ошибки добавьте в сам вопрос в виде текста.

Comment: А вообще, вот эта строка `bssd1=BSSID.get().replace(":","",1)` у вас выполняется сразу при старте программы, когда в поле BSSID еще пусто, поэтому в bssd1 всегда пустая строка. Нужно переместить эту строку в функцию play, чтобы текст из поля получался только после того как была нажата кнопка.